# Pass variable to callback method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

This question has little to do with jQueryUI's dialog, and more to do with JavaScript.

I pass some variables to `ayb.dialogError()`, and use them to create a dialog.  Then I pass different values, but the first are still used.

The below script is condensed to highlight the issues, and the full script is located at https://jsbin.com/muhijodima.

Within the `open` callback, how do I access the variables passed to `ayb.dialogError()`?

```
$(function(){

    ayb={};
    ayb.dialogErrorElem=undefined;

    ayb.dialogError=function(t,e) {
        if (typeof ayb.dialogErrorElem === 'undefined') {
            ayb.dialogErrorElem=$('<div/>').appendTo('body').dialog({
                open: function(event, ui){
                    console.log('dialog.open',t,e);
                    //t=function(){return t;}
                    //e=function(){return e;}
                },
            });
            console.log(ayb.dialogErrorElem);
        };
        ayb.dialogErrorElem.dialog('open');
    }

    $('#e1').click(function(){ayb.dialogError('Title1',['error1-1','error1-2'])});
    $('#e2').click(function(){ayb.dialogError('Title2','error2-1')});

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the variables passed to ayb.dialogError()"? `t` and `e` parameters? They should be available inside that callback.

Comment: Trailing comma at `},` ? following `console.log('dialog.open',t,e);` ?

Comment: @hindmost  But they are not.  On the jsbin demo, try clicking one of the buttons, then the other.  The second time, the `e` and `t` parameters still use the ones from the first time.

Comment: @guest271314  Shouldn't matter.

Comment: @hindmost  I only pass the parameters when the dialog is first created, therefore of course it will only use the valves.  Instead I need the callback not to use them as they were when first created, but somehow get them from above.  That is why I was thinking they should be `t=function(){return t;}`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Consider removing `if (typeof ayb.dialogErrorElem ..` statement and replacing `ayb.dialogErrorElem` element each time `dialogError` is called. This will ensure passing appropriate `t` and `e` parameters.

Comment: @hindmost  Yes, I agree that will work.  From a mater of learning, I would like to know how I can have the `open` callback use the passed parameters.

Comment: Just save them in some variables outside `dialogError`, then `dialogErrorElem` will always have the updated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect this is not the best way to do so, however, the passed parameters are available to the `open` callback.

Condensed script below to highlight concept, and full script at https://jsbin.com/segoxewape/edit?html,output.

If there is a better way to make the parameters available in the callback (which I am sure there is), please comment.

```
ayb.dialogError=function(t,e) {
    getEm=function(){return {e:e,t:t};}
    var v={e:e,t:t};    //Won't work
    if (typeof this.dialog === 'undefined') {
        this.dialog=$('<div/>', {})
        .dialog({
            open: function(event, ui){
                console.log('Wrong values in dialog.open!',t,e,v.t,v.e);
                var o=getEm();
                console.log('Right values!',o);
            }
        });
    };
    this.dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At `if (typeof ayb.dialogErrorElem === 'undefined') {`

`ayb.dialogErrorElem` is not `undefined` at click of `two` `button`

jsbin https://jsbin.com/rugarizedo/edit?html,output

Comment: Yes, that was my intention as I thought it was wasteful not to do so.  And I understand why the results I get are exactly as they should be.  Within the `open` callback, my hopes were to use some additional callback to get the `e` and `t` values.

Comment: Tried setting  `ayb.dialogErrorElem` back to `undefined` at `close` event ?

Comment: I appreciate your post and I agree creating the element each time or setting it back to `undefined` will work, but the question is how do I use passed parameters in the callback.

Comment: @user1032531 https://jsbin.com/kiyuhodago/1/edit?html,output . Added `ayb.dialogErrorElem=undefined;` following `$(this).dialog("close");` See output , `console`